# How is the `-l` in the header `#!/bin/bash -l` different from using #SBATCH --get-user-env=L?

Tags: bash, queue, slurm

The `-l` flag in this job file refers to executing as if it was in the login node right? Meaning that it will first read ~/.bash_profile. How is this different from using #SBATCH --get-user-env=L?

Will the latter flag only read environment variables and not the rest from ~/.bash_profile?

Not sure whether is it better to use one or the other.
Also don't know if `--export NONE` will override both of these options.

```
#!/bin/bash -l

#SBATCH --account project_id 
#SBATCH --mail-type ALL     
#SBATCH --chdir /scratch/<your_username>/
#SBATCH --job-name my_code 
#SBATCH --output my_code.out
#SBATCH --partition cpu
#SBATCH --nodes 1 
#SBATCH --ntasks 1 
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 8 
#SBATCH --mem 10G 
#SBATCH --time 00:30:00 
#SBATCH --export NONE
#SBATCH --get-user-env=L
```

Comment: `-l` means that the script, if executed via its #! line, is run as login shell, which in turn means that various login-specific files are executed. Your .bash_profile will be one of them. I don't know _slurm_ and can't comment on your SBATCH question. However, your remark _read environment variables_ does not make sense to me. Usually, environment variables are not "read" from somewhere. They spring into existence if some code is **executed** which sets them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the [docs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_get-user-env), it seems like they do the same thing.

But in the end, the behavior depends on how Slurm executes your script. You may be aware that there are two different ways you can execute a Bash script yourself:

```bash
./script.sh
```

```bash
bash ./script.sh
```

If Slurm does the equivalent of the former, then that means that your `-l` flag takes effect and the script is ran by a Bash login shell. In this case, the Linux kernel looks at the file, looks at the shebang, and runs Bash with the `-l` argument.

However, if Slurm does the equivalent of the latter, then that means your `-l` flag has no effect. In this case, Bash reads the file, and ignores the first line because it is a comment.

Therefore, I would recommend setting `#SBATCH --get-user-env=L`, because that is a guarantee by Slum that the script will executable in a login shell.  Adding `-l` may not have an effect (one would have to look at the source code to be sure, and even then, it is possible the behavior can change since it is an implementation detail).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what --export NONE does exactly? where are variables being exported?

Comment: Variables can be exported in several other locations. You may be able to set environment variables in `/etc/environment`, `~/.pam_environment`. On Linux, every process has a set of environment variables associated with it. When Slurm runs one of your Bash scripts, the environment of that Bash script is copied from the environment of Slurm (from what I can tell). When Linux process executes another Linux process (this is a child process), the environment variables are copied. So...

Comment: So, if a computer has Slurm installed, and in its `/etc/environment` file, it says `export FOO=myvalue`, then if your script is running on that computer, then the `FOO` environment variable should have a value of `myvalue` (`echo "$FOO"`). With `--export NONE`, according to the docs, then `FOO` will no longer be available to you as an environment variable in the script - because the environment variable does not start with `SLURM_`

Comment: Note that I'm not completely sure about how SLURM works, it could be so that `/etc/environment` has no effect - but however the environment variable is set, that is how `--export NONE` works.

Comment: Note that Slurm `exec`'s the script so this corresponds to the first case you list.  Also note that `--get-user-env` will not overwrite variables already defined at submit time, while `bash -l` will.